# Can I use Strongly type parameters based on properties from Object

Tags: c#, linq, generics, extension-methods

I have a list of objects.
I have a single item with same type as the list.

I would like to create a generic extension method (called **Find**) to find an item from the list based on the single obj as well as an arbitrary list of its strongly typed properties.

Here is how I would like to call the method:

```
var obj = new SomeObject() { ... } ;
var list = new List<SomeObject>() { ... };

// Find similar objects
list.Find(obj, x => x.Id,y => y.Description);
```

Is this arrangement possible?

FirstOrDefault would work as in the comment below. However, I am looking for a way to use the pattern in different scenarios that might not be a simple lookup.

Comment: There already exists an extension method called `Find`, and as suggested, `FirstOrDefault` will also do the same job easily. If you need to find all elements in the list that satifies your condition, use the `Where` extension method

Comment: Are you attempting to Find a single result or multiple results based on matching property values?

Comment: I am more interested in how I might be able to use this pattern or not in a scenario other than the simplified problem I gave here. An example might be lookup some type information and print based on the given properties.

Comment: i updated my answer. see if it is what you are looking for. if it is not could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
public static T Find<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params Func<T,bool>[] condition)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(o => condition.All(f => f(o))); // use All for && or use Any for ||
}
```

And to use it

```
var item = list.Find(x=> x.Id == obj.Id,x=> x.Description == obj.Description);
```

You can use Object if you want to make this work more generally by casting properties to object. but this will be a bit slower by the way and you must note that the `Equals` method for **custom types** must be overriden in order to make it work.

```
public static T Find<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T obj, params Func<T, object>[] condition)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(o => condition.All(f => f(o).Equals(f(obj))));
}
```

Then you can call it exactly like this.

```
var item = list.Find(obj, x => x.Id,y => y.Description);
```

You can use `Where` if you want to return all similar items. by just changing `FirstOrDefault` into `Where` and the return type of method into `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I understand your logic but I was thinking something generic in terms of the comparison so I can just pass the parameters. It would be really cool if  C# could infer the variable. Maybe Microsoft could provide a params<T> concept. Then you could call the method like so public static DoSomething(o.Id, o.Description) .

Comment: @jwize you can use `dynamic` type which its actual type is evaluated at runtime. but it would be much slower since the type is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to me like you're saving a lot of time/effort versus just using a normal Where clause that filters on whichever properties you're after.

```
var findResults = list.Where(x => x.Id == obj.Id || x.Description == obj.Description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider proceeding like this:

```cs
var myResult = from currentObject in mylist
               where currentObject == mySingleObject // change it by your matching criterias linked by && or || (as in if ...)
               // NB: you can also override the == operator in your object definition
               // but as mentionned below, it won't work for generic types
               select currentObject;
```

Comment: operator overloading would not work in Find<T> where the T is not known.